# How to implement an event system

Tags: c#, performance, event-handling

Im trying to implement an Event System for a game, where there are classes that can fire or handle an event wheter or not they implement these interfaces:

```
public interface IGameEvent<T> where T : EventArgs
{
     event EventHandler<T> OnEvent;
}

public interface IGameHandler<T> where T : EventArgs
{
    void OnEvent(object sender, T e);
}
```

everything looked great until i realized that no class can implement more than 1 IGameEvent
because it would cause duplicate declaration,

Here is an example:

```
public class Event
{
    public KeyPressEvent OnKeyPress;
    public UpdateEvent OnUpdate;

    public void AddHadler<T>(IGameEvent<T> eEvent , IGameHandler<T> eHandler) where  T : EventArgs
    {
        eEvent.OnEvent += eHandler.OnEvent;
    }

    public void RemoveHandler<T>(IGameEvent<T> eEvent, IGameHandler<T> eHandler) where T : EventArgs
    {
        eEvent.OnEvent -= eHandler.OnEvent;
    }
}
```

KeyPressEvent:

```
public class KeyPressEvent : IGameEvent<KeyPressEvent.KeyPressedEventArgs>
{
    public class KeyPressedEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public KeyPressedEventArgs(Keys key)
        {
            Key = key;
        }

        public Keys Key { get; private set; }
    }

    public event EventHandler<KeyPressedEventArgs> OnEvent;

    private void OnCheckForKeyPressed()  //Example
    {
        if (OnEvent != null) 
            OnEvent(this, new KeyPressedEventArgs(Keys.Space));
    }
}
```

Would be better to manually store the suscribers in a list in the EventSystem ?

How slower or faster than this approach that would be?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The common approach is to implement events aggregator pattern. Google search will provide you with tons of different variations. For example, it might look like this (what i am currently using):

```
interface IEventsAggrgator
{
    //fires an event, reperesented by specific message
    void Publish<TMessage>(TMessage message);
    //adds object to the list of subscribers
    void Subscribe(object listener);
    //remove object from the list of subscribers
    void Unsubscribe(object listener);
}

interface IHandler<TMessage>
{
    //implement this in subscribers to handle specific messages
    void Handle(TMessage message);
}
```